# regex replace in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've never really used regex so this is probably a basic question, but I need to reformat a string in javascript/jquery and I think regex is the direction to go.

How can I convert this string:

```
\"1\",\"2\",\"\\",\"\4\"
```

into:

```
"1","2","","4"
```

These are both strings, so really they'd be contained in `""` but I thought that may confuse things even more.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var value = '\"1\",\"2\",\"\\",\"\4\"'.replace(/\"/, '"').replace(/"\//, '"');
```

Comment: why are you not replacing only \ ..does it need to be before `"` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var value = your_string.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

to remove all the "\"

Comment: thanks, this doesn't appear to do anything, in chrome's console i entered:  $('.inputParameters').val().replace(/\//g, "");
which returned "\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"\\"" where $('.inputParameters').val() contains the original value

Comment: 1. `$("inputParameters").val()` will not be changed, until you change it with `val(newvalue)` 2. Seems like `"\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"\\""` has an extra slash or an unescaped quote at the end

Comment: thanks for the help, i have it now, needed to be /\\/g instead of /\//g

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot of escaping... Your string is:

```
var str = '\\"1\\",\\"2\\",\\"\\\\",\\"\\4\\"'

console.log(str.replace(/\\/g, '')) // "1","2","","4"
```

However, if you want only to replace `\"` with `"` use:

```
console.log(str.replace(/\\"/g, '"')) // "1","2","\","\4"
```